# Getting import EOF errors with scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, installation

I've installed scikit-learn, and I tried running some code snippets from their website, but the import seems to be causing trouble. I keep getting EOF error with any code that uses scikit:

```
measurements = [
    {'city': 'Dubai', 'temperature': 33.},
    {'city': 'London', 'temperature': 12.},
    {'city': 'San Francisco', 'temperature': 18.},
]

from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vec = DictVectorizer()

vec.fit_transform(measurements).toarray()




vec.get_feature_names()
```

I tried other snippets, the error is always the same:

```
py cosine.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cosine.py", line 12, in <module>
    from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
  File "C:\Users\haas_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import text
  File "C:\Users\haas_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import normalize
  File "C:\Users\haas_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer
  File "C:\Users\haas_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..utils.testing import assert_allclose_dense_sparse
  File "C:\Users\haas_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py", line 751, in <module>
    import pytest
  File "C:\Users\haas_\Desktop\pytest.py", line 268

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Seems to be a problem with the installation? I've tried uninstalling and then installing everything again-- Numpy, Scipy, scikit-learn (always with pip). I've also tried creating virtual environment with Anaconda, same problem.

None of the similar threads helped me with this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try renaming the `Desktop\pytest.py` file to something else

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing that, but it wasn't the issue.

I finally solved the issue, after going berserk and un-istalling python and all of its packages, then installing everything again.
Still have no idea what the issue was, though...